# why should I not use CDN for react & babel?

Tags: reactjs, cdn, babeljs

When I was learning jQuery & Bootstrap, we (my fellow noobs learning web frameworks) were told CDN had a whole bunch of benefits and such.

Now that I am dabbling in React/Babel, we are told that we should download the files and have it all ready and good from our host server. But we are still capable of using CDN but for prototyping & development only and not suggested for production usage.

I thought the point of using CDN is to save money, bandwidth, etc.

I am referencing these statements:

Babel: [Compiling in the browser has a fairly limited use case, so if you are working on a production site you should be precompiling your scripts server-side](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation)

React: "[The versions above are only meant for development, and are not suitable for production. Minified and optimized production versions of React are available.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html)" (the bottom of the page)

```
class Button1 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.but = null;
    }
    render() {
        let c = 'mdc-button mdc-button--raised mdc-button--primary mdc-ripple-upgraded';
        let l = e('label', {}, this.props.label);
        let i = iconToggle(this.props.icon);
        this.but = e('button', {className: c, onClick: () => {toggleLights()}}, l, i);
        return e('div', {className: 'myCenter'}, this.but);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess react's instruction suggest the production CDN is minified. So I'm guessing they remove error messages and hints, etc. But I've noticed almost every tutorial on Youtube start with downloading and installing through npm instead of using CDN. I feel like I am missing some key information here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit:**

You are using [React without JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html).

> **React Without JSX**
>
> JSX is not a requirement for using React. Using
>   React without JSX is especially convenient when you don't want to set
>   up compilation in your build environment.

As you don't need to compile your program in your computer, you can include `react.min.js` without any problem.

Babel is used to convert(compiles) JSX to JavaScript which is not advised 
 to do it in browser as I stated below.

Most of the tutorials in the web are about using JSX because it is one of the advantage of using React. JSX is a syntactic sugar. You can write less code with JSX.

Try this [online Babel compiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0&code=function%20hello()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%3Cdiv%3EHello%20world!%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3B%0A%7D) to see how JSX is converted to JavaScript and how much more code is generated.

So, if you are using [React without JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html), then using CDN to fetch React library is faster than hosting it in your server. It works same like jQuery and Bootstrap. You don't need to include Babel as you are not using JSX.

---

Why you should not use CDN is present in the same Facebook page you have given.

> If you prefer to use your own text editor, you can also download this
>   HTML file, edit it, and open it from the local filesystem in your
>   browser. It does a slow runtime code transformation, so don't use it
>   in production.

To say it clearly,

**Using CDN:**

As Facebook said, it does a slow runtime code transformation in the browser.

That is your code doesn't execute right-away.

First your code should be converted to JavaScript so that browsers can execute it, as JSX is not supported.

After the conversion to JavaScript, then the browsers execute it.

***On client's browser:***

```
JSX -> JavaScript -> Execute
```

**Using compiled (production version):**

When you compile the JSX to JavaScript, you are saving lots of time by avoiding runtime code transformation in the client's browser.

Usually compiling does code optimisations and produces final resulting code.

Then you can minify it to replace long variables with short variable names, removing comments, removing extra empty lines etc to reduce the size. Then the file is gzipped and transferred to the client's browser. This stage(minify and gzip) reduces the size and saves bandwidth and increases webpage render times.

***On your computer:***

```
JSX -> JavaScript -> minified JavaScript
```

***On client's browser:***

```
JavaScript -> Execute
```

In programming, the most resource intense work is compiling the code. (Executing depends on code/logic)

So, you are doing the most resource intense task in your computer and sending the simple JavaScript to execute which reduces the work to be done by browser which results in faster loads of webpage and less CPU work on client's browser(some users can be using slow computers and your webpage may hang their computers due to using too much resources).

Comment: I'm not talking about minified or JSX. The CDN for React is already pure JavaScript and minified. I'm just talking about CDN vs downloading it.

Comment: @DeadSupra I think you didn't read it correctly. How do you think JSX will be executed in the browser?

Comment: yeah I don't see JSX in the code. maybe because its minified its somewhere deep in the code? Either way, if I were to download this same code from the CDN, all I would do is serve it from my own server. So what would be the difference if you are serving JSX from a CDN versus JSX from my server?

Comment: also, I don't use JSX, myself. I do use ES6 though. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: @DeadSupra can you post a snippet of your component?

Comment: I guess I still lose some load time for ES6 compilation though. I posted this question a while ago and now that I reread it, I included a minification example. Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: @DeadSupra Most of the desktop browsers support some features of ES6(so there is no slow load time.). If you want to use ES5(to support some mobile and old browsers), then use Babel to convert ES6 to ES5 or follow [React Without ES6](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html)

Comment: Unless the question has been edited since this answer, this answer seems to talk about why you should build/transpile the code before deploying to the server. But the question I see asked is "Should I include the React library in my bundle, or should I have my bundle pull the React library from a CDN?" Even the babel-built code needs the React library when it's run in the browser.

Comment: @EricMajerus I think you didn't clearly understand what the OP is asking. The explanation I gave is for this sentence in the question specifically: **But we are still capable of using CDN but for prototyping & development only and not suggested for production usage.** Initially the OP didn't post code snippet. So I thought the OP must be using JSX like most of them do and I gave answer about how it works. Later the OP clarified he/she is not using any JSX. For the part you are asking, just read the **Edit** part of the answer.